# I do not get what expected on a regex expression

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for words in text6 that either contain a z or the sequence of characters pt or end with ize

I wrote the following but it includes many words that do not meet the above criteria like appease,dance,offensive,executive.... Why is this happening?

```
L2=[w for w in text6 if re.search(r".*[z]|.*[p][t]|[ize]$",w)
```

Another question building up on the previous exercise: I need to add a new alternative condition i.e. that the words starts with 1 and only 1 capital letter.

I wrote

```
L2=[w for w in text6 if re.search(r"[A-Z]{1}|.*[z]|.*[p][t]|[ize]$",w)
```

It includes also upper case words (i.e all characters in capital letter)

How can I resolve these questions?

Comment: In your first case, is `ize$` necessary? Any word contains this pattern will also be captured by `z` alone?

Answer (score 2):

You are iterating over the characters not the words, for that case you need to split your text.

Also you can do all of these jobs without regex:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase

def check_word(word):
    return 'z' in word or 'pt' in word or word.endswith('ize') or word.startswith(tuple(ascii_uppercase))

[w for w in text6.split() if check_word(w)]
```

Demo :

```
>>> text6 = "here are some example: appease dance offensive xxxize executive and other extra words optimum Python"
>>> [w for w in text6.split() if check_word(w)]
['xxxize', 'optimum', 'Python']
```

For the last condition (*the words starts with 1 and only 1 capital letter*) if you don't want any upper case in word except the first one you can add (`word[1:].islower()`) to `check_word` function:

```
def check_word(word):
    return 'z' in word or 'pt' in word or word.endswith('ize') or (word.startswith(tuple(ascii_uppercase)) and word[1:].islower())
```

*Note*: If you want to separate the words with multiple delimiter or based on another condition you can use `re.findall()` in order to find the words.

For example the following regex will wind the words contain word characters:

```
re.findall(r'\b\w+\b', my_str)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a non-regex approach here, since regex seems more complicated than this use case demands.

For one, you can get rid of the "ends in `ize`" constraint, because that falls under any words with `z` in it.

```
text6 = [
    'appease', 'dance', 'offensive', 'executive',
    'inept', 'zoo', 'Inept', 'Zoo', 'INept', 'ZOo']
```

For just matching words with lowercased `pt` or `z`:

```
[w for w in text6 if 'pt' in w or 'z' in w]  # ['inept', 'zoo', 'Inept', 'INept']
```

For matching the above cases as well as only capitalized words:

```
[w for w in text6 if w.istitle() and ('pt' in w or 'z' in w)]  # ['Inept']
```

Of course, it may be better to write a function that abstracts this logic out:

```
def meets_criteria(word):
    return word.istitle() and ('pt' in word or 'z' in word)

[w for w in text6 if meets_criteria(w)]
```

If you want to also match words starting with `Z` and `Pt`, you can check membership in `w.lower()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is:

```
[w for w in text6 if re.search(r"z|pt|ize$", w)]
```

This will capture all the required words. Note that, the last part is not required as any word matching `ize$` will also match `z`. So essentially, the expression boils down to:

```
[w for w in text6 if re.search(r"z|pt", w)]
```

The second case can be solved by using the expression `^[A-Z]{1}[^A-Z]`. That is,

- Starts with exactly one capital letter
- Isn't followed by a capital letter

This is used below:

```
[w for w in text6 if re.search(r"^[A-Z]{1}[^A-Z]|z|pt|ize$", w)]
```

Or, simply,

```
[w for w in text6 if re.search(r"^[A-Z]{1}[^A-Z]|z|pt", w)]
```

Comment: This is assuming that `text6` is a `list` of words. If not, run the loop on `text6.split()` instead, as pointed out by @Kasramvd